# What is the use of the next() function for printing the size of an array?

Tags: python, pytorch

I have been reading about how to use Pytorch for the MNIST character recognition, so far the code is the following:

```
import torch
import torchvision

train_loader=torch.utils.data.DataLoader(torchvision.datasets.MNIST('/files/',train=True, download=True,
                                                                    transform=torchvision.transforms.Compose(
                                                                        [torchvision.transforms.ToTensor(),
                                                                         torchvision.transforms.Normalize((0.1307), (0.3081))
                                                                            ])),
                                         batch_size=batch_size_train,shuffle=True)

test_loader=torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
    torchvision.datasets.MNIST('/files/',train=False,download=True,
                               transform=torchvision.transforms.Compose(
                                   [torchvision.transforms.ToTensor(),
                                    torchvision.transforms.Normalize(
                                        (0.1307,),(0.3081,))
                                       ])),
    batch_size=batch_size_test,shuffle=True
    )

examples=enumerate(test_loader)
batch_idx,(example_data,example_targets)=next(examples)
```

However, the problem is the last line:

```
batch_idx,(example_data,example_targets)=next(examples)
```

I could replace it by:

```
example_data,example_targets=next(examples)
```

and the program compiles, but when I want to do the following:

```
print (example_data.shape)
```

Only the first version of `batch_idx,(example_data,example_targets)` works, but not the second one without the `batch_idx` part.

Also, when I print the value of `batch_idx` always returns `0`. So, my question is what is the use of this `batch_idx` part, why it has the value of 0 and the relationship with the `next()` and `shape` functions?

Comment: `examples` is an iterable of tuples, with its second element itself being another 2-element tuple. The last line is somewhat like `x, (y, z) = (1, (2, 3))`. Your change is the same as `x, y = (1, (2, 3))`. The target names in your change no longer correspond to the values actually being assigned to them.

Answer (score 1):

`examples` is an iterable. It could consist of *many* tuples; `next` simply returns the *next* one. Let's say that tuple is `(1, (2, 3))`.

In the original code, you have

batch_idx,(example_data,example_targets)=(1, (2, 3))

which results in `batch_idx == 1`, `example_data == 2`, and `example_targets == 3`.

With your change,

```
example_data,example_targets=(1, (2, 3))
```

you would have `example_data == 1` and `example_targets == (2, 3)`. The *names* you assign to have nothing to do with what values are extracted from the tuple.

If all you want are the elements of the inner tuple, and you don't care about the first element of the outer tuple, you still need to unpack the full structure. The convention, though, is to assign values you don't care about to the dummy name `_`:

```
_, (example_data, example_targets) = next(elements)
```

or explicitly extract the tuple you want to unpack before the assignment.

```
example_data, example_targets = next(elements)[1]
```